# Can't write to sdcard even with permissions set and external storage in MEDIA_MOUNTED state

Tags: android, io

While trying to write file to sdcard I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /filename (Read-only file system)` exception. Sadly none of the many solutions posted here helped me. I have set the permissions and external storage is in MEDIA_MOUNTED state.
This is the problematic code:

```
Log.i("STORAGE", Environment.getExternalStorageState());
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Helpers.StripExtension(filePath) + ".blk");
fos.write(digest.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

`filePath` comes from file ticker. What I'm trying to do is reading from chosen file, and then saving another file with the same name, different extension and some stuff in it.

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="mypackagename"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Logcat:

```
 10-25 18:24:34.330: I/FILEPATH(1989): /mnt/sdcard/Untitled.txt
 10-25 18:24:34.360: I/STORAGE(1989): mounted
 10-25 18:24:34.360: W/System.err(1989): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Untitled.blk (Read-only file system)
 10-25 18:24:34.360: W/System.err(1989):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
 10-25 18:24:34.360: W/System.err(1989):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
 10-25 18:24:34.360: W/System.err(1989):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
 10-25 18:24:34.360: W/System.err(1989):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
 10-25 18:24:34.360: W/System.err(1989):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:144)
```

I'm running this on a real device, not avd. I've tried rebooting my device and rebuilding project. Applications like OfficeSuite can write to this location with no problem.

Device: ZTE Blade with Android 2.3.7 (CyanogenMod 7)

Comment: Did you try to write that into an dir not the root of the sd card ? String withDir = Environment.getExternalStorageState() + "/someDir/" + fileName; File file = new File(withDir); file.mkdirs(); or similar...

Comment: the main question is: why is your sdcard mounted as read only? Which device do you use? which android version?

Comment: I had a similar situation and it was a bad sdcard. Thing was, some programs would work, but come to find out that on reboot any changes to the sdcard didn't stick, so I'm assuming that it was accepted into a buffer, but the buffer was never able to flush and write it out, giving the illusion that it was there when in fact it was not

Comment: @WarrenFaith Funny thing is that `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` says it's mounted as rw (according to [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)).
I will update my question with system specs.

Comment: What @DrakeClarris said could be your case, too. If possible, change the sdcard. Another possibility you should check is the emulator and a device running stock android. CM might be good but I would try checking against other android roms, too.

Comment: Can you show us what `adb shell mount` outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, I've had the exact same problem some time ago. Path delimiter (or whatever it's called) is missing.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "test_file.blk");
```

didn't work, but

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test_file.blk");
```

performed well

Also:

```
FileWriter f = new FileWriter(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/foobar");
f.append("stuff");
f.close();
```

Works fine etc.
I think exceptions said it's readonly, because root filesystem is readonly indeed.

NOTE:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /foobar (Read-only file system)` means we are writing to the system root
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/foobar (Read-only file system)` means sdcard root (I didn't get this exception it's just an example)

**tl;dr** wrong path

Comment: Strange, I can write to sdcard root without problem. Actually files on the sdcard are not permitted to be executed for security reasons, but you can write, or else you couldn't create folders on it. But if your own solution worked you should mark your own answer as correct. :)

Comment: To clarify: I tried to (by mistake) write to system root, not sdcard root :)
BTW, 2 days cooldown before marking my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(Helpers.StripExtension(filePath) + ".blk");
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(digest.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

and if that doesn't work, I think you may have a problem when reading from the original file (`digest.getBytes()`). Post a little more code on this and we can go from there

Edit:

If it is not letting you write to the selected directory, try testing with a path like this:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "test_file.blk");
```

It should work fine and you probably just don't have write permissions to the directory you are using.

Comment: Changing this line as suggested gives `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /newFile/Untitled.blk (No such file or directory)`.
I'm sure reading from the original file is not the problem because exception is being thrown at the `OutputStream fos = ...` line, also changing `digest.getBytes()` to some string, doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you try the second solution in the answer?  Explicitly creating the file, then writing to it may provide a more clear problem.

Comment: Second solution gives `java.io.IOException: Read-only file system` at `file.createNewFile();` line.

Comment: Then you are writing to a directory the device does not have permission to write to.  What is the directory path before 'Untitled.blk'? Refer to an edit I just made on my answer

Comment: /mnt/sdcard  
`GetExternalStorageDirectory()` gives /mnt/sdcard  
I'm pretty sure I saved some files to sdcard root before from my app. But now I have exceptions.

Comment: If you are still debugging on a device, make sure your SD card is not mounted to your computer. I would start the app and disconnect it completely from your computer just to be sure. Something is locking your SD card. If you are using the emulator, Google the error because emulating an SD card can be really tricky depending on your SDK version

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File file = new File(filePath);
File parent = file.getParentFile();
if (!parent.exists() && !parent.mkdirs()) {
      return;
}

file = new File(Helpers.StripExtension(filePath) + ".blk");
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(digest.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Comment: Gives 'W/System.err(5180): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /foobar.blk (Read-only file system)' at `OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);` line