# Can't write to /mnt/sdcard

Tags: android

This one has me stumped (Android 4.3)

I have the right permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

... I'm explicitly creating a path to /storage/sdcard0/path/to/data.csv and the FileOutputStream doesn't throw any exceptions.

I tried reading the path via `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` but that has some "emulated" path.

In either case, I can't see the files on the filesystem ...

What's more confusing is that `MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY`is mounted_ro ... but this isn't the case .

It looks like another app us using /mnt/extSdCard... I tried hard coding that in my app but that doesn't work either.  Even the directory is missing.  This is very confusing.

I'm calling `mkdirs()` on this of course and the FileOutputStream is created....

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was the device plugged into a computer when you ran your code?

Comment: You should be using the "emulated" path returned by the API - also be aware that the mount locations which adb sees *are not the same* as those which an application sees / uses.

Comment: could you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13078328/2683275) ? and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820148/cannot-write-to-sd-card-on-android-phone) also.

Comment: The device was plugged in via USB .. but I re-ran it when not on USB and I still had the same problem.

Comment: Ah... it WAS related to the USB being connected.  But there are some weird things happening.  no IOException was being thrown...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, and see where it fails?

```
        try {
            File mPath = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"path/to");
            if (!mPath.exists()) {
                if(!mPath.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Can't Create Folder: "+mPath.getName());
                }
            }
            File mLogFile = new File(mPath, "data.csv");
            FileWriter mFileWriter = null;
            if(mPath.canWrite()) {
                mFileWriter = new FileWriter(mLogFile, true);
                mBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(mFileWriter);
            }
            else {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Can't write under Folder: "+mPath.getName());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```