# Android writing file with bad permissions

Tags: android, android-file, android-permissions

When I write a file to the sdcard, it writes the file with permissions -rw-rw---- and the owner as root. I followed the android guidelines for file write permissions, but it didn't say anything about writing the file as root. I need to be able to open this file with a android file manager, but don't have the privileges since I'm not rooted. 
This is the code for outputting the file:

```
 File file = getExternalStorageDirectory();

 File sim = new File(file, "Driving Sim App/");
 sim.getParentFile().mkdirs();
 sim = new File(sim, name+".csv");

 try {
     BufferedWriter bor = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(sim)));
     bor.write("This is a test");
     bor.close();
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     return;
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

I also have this in my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your file permissions appears to reflect normal and proper behavior of the fuse daemon involved.  There is no real sense of per-package file ownership on the external storage, rather it is membership in the appropriate unix group (following from a manifest permission) which should enable access from the middle permission set which in your case is rw-.  The per-package directories in later versions add permission synthesize as an additional possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:
`File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`

Answer (score 0):

Two potential fixes to your problem. First, make sure your path is formatted correctly. Print out the path to sim and make sure it does not have any extra slashes or missing slashes.
All of these are problematic:

```
parent_dir//child_dir.csv
parent_dirchild_dir.csv
parent_dir/child_dir/.csv
parent_dir/child_dir.csv/
```

Really you want this:

```
parent_dir/child_dir.csv
```

The other possible issue I'm aware of is a reindexing problem on some Android devices. This means that on some Android devices, even if you are successfully writing your files, they might not be visible to you in storage (this is assuming you aren't getting errors when you try to write a file).

Fix this by reindexing using the MediaScannerConnection object.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null,
        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
            }
});
```

^^I got this from another post for a similar issue when I was struggling with something like this:
[Can't write to sdcard even with permissions set and external storage in MEDIA_MOUNTED state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073633/cant-write-to-sdcard-even-with-permissions-set-and-external-storage-in-media-mo)